# Error @angular-devkit when creating new project with angular/cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I can't create new project with my `@angular/cli` `ng new` command

everytime I run `ng new PROJECT_NAME`, it gives me this error

```
npm ERR! path D:\angular\project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\angular\project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript' -> 'D:\angular\project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\.typescript.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\denny\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-27T13_31_25_837Z-debug.log
Error: Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

---

```
Version :
-Node: v9.8.0
-npm: v5.6.0
-Angular CLI: v1.7.3
```

I've tried `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`, `npm cache clean --force`, and `npm install -g @angular/cli` but it still doesn't work.. Please help me guys.. Thanks!

EDITTED:

I even clean uninstall all my `node.js` and reinstall the LTS version which `v8.10.0` and it still gives me the same error.. when I run `ng -v` in my 'fail-created-project',  it gives me this :

```
PS D:\angular\first-project> ng -v

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: error
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router


@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: error
typescript: error
webpack: error
```

Comment: kindly check if you have two versions installed, if ng -v and node -v shows different  version of node then you should have to re-install node after removing it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the past. You should run `npm install @angular-devkit --save-dev`. It will resolve the issue.

Comment: How does this work if the OP hasn't even been able to `ng new` a project yet?

Comment: In my case, the project was created with `ng new PROJECT_NAME`, but I got the error related to @angular-devkit.

Comment: @DamienGold I did this but it still give me error `npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@angular-devkit": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes`

Comment: @DamienGold should i run it globally or just in project?

Comment: Invalid tag name "@angular-devkit":Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.